Help with hip and thigh rigging

I'm working with this model I downloaded from Mixamo.  The rigging is mostly good but the hips and thighs are very messed up as you can see in the sample.  I show the mesh which looks detailed enough.
The center crotch area is being dragged and deforming the other inner thigh.  Obviously this shouldn't happen in real life spandex or bare skin.  The side hip-thigh crease is caving in a lot.  I think I need to either add bones and/or use weight painting but I'm not sure.  Does anyone have any advice?

Hello could you please share your file (only share the useful part)? https://blend-exchange.com/

The file can be downloaded from Mixamo.  The character is Jennifer.  Here's the full link.
https://www.mixamo.com/#/?page=1&query=jennifer&type=Character

It's hard to get the thigh to deform correctly with just one bone, so the usual practice is to add a shape key and a driver, it's called a corrective shape key.
Here is a tutorial from Royal Skies, the only difference in your case is that you need to set a different axis for the driver.
Also this playlist explains shape keys really well

https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382/what-is-wrong-about-answering-with-a-link

@HarryMcKenzie I know answering with a link isn't the best I can do, but should we answer questions that have been asked before with small changes? Should I send a link to a similar question/answer?

Thank you, I will give it a try.

probably mark as a duplicate maybe? Can you share a link that is similar to this?

I tried to use the shape key using the Royal Skies tutorial.  This isn't working for some reason in Blender 4.1.1.  I added a driver using the left thigh armature rotating on the Y axis and used the same expression formula he showed in the video and tried to change it a little but value always shows 0.  But the effect of the modification is left permanently on at max strength so that when I move the left thigh bone back to normal, there's now a big bulge in the left hip-thigh crease.  It looks good when living the left leg fully but anything else shows an increasing bulge.

Make sure that the expression works and the variable has the right name. You can pick the right equation yourself to make the Shape key change from 0 to 1 in 90 degrees of rotation.

I finally got it working somehow by using the XYZ ruler, and using the Z axis rotation even though the bone was clearly rotating the Y axis.  In fact when I hit R and Y, it rotates it how I want.  But in the XYZ Euler, it was showing a number changing from 0 to 1 in the Z rotation axis.
I had already applied rotation to the armature because it came from Mixamo pre-rotated.  But it still changed on the Z axis as far as the Driver was concerned.  I ended up using the formula var * 1.4.

@GeorgeOu Rigging can be hard, and why the axis was different than you'd think is because bones have mean tilt and local rotation, you can see this by enabling the axis overlay in the armature/bone tab.

I guess there are several solutions, like creating a shapekey that will correc the bad deformation, with a driver to trigger the shapekey, also you could create another bone that will control this part. At last you could give a Smooth Corrective modifier to your object, you can limit its effect on a vertex group only:

